# Matlab: Can't run class method as a normal function?

Tags: matlab, class, oop, methods

I've defined a class `cMyClass`, with a method as a separate m-file `SomeMethod.m` within the `@cMyClass` folder.  I can invoke `SomeMethod` as a normal function (rather than a method) as long as it is copied outside of folder `@cMyClass`.  When the current working directory is the folder `@cMyClass`, however, `SomeMethod` is not recognized (I supply an empty struct as the argument in place of the expected host object).  I've tried `clear classes` and `rehash` after changing folders to `@cMyClass`, but they don't help.

This takes away a convenience in tactical testing and troubleshooting.  I'm wondering if such a behaviour is really hard coded into Matlab, or is there something that I'm missing?  The test code is as follows.

The class definition `@cMyClass/cMyClass.m`:

```
% @cMyClass/cMyClass.m
% --------------------
classdef cMyClass < handle
   methods
      SomeMethod(o)
   end % methods
end % classdef
```

The method definition in `@cMyClass/SomeMethod.m`:

```
% @cMyClass/SomeMethod.m
% ----------------------
function SomeMethod(o)
'Hello world'
end % function
```

I succeeded in the conventional invocation of `SomeMethod` as a class method:

```
>> oMyClass = cMyClass
oMyClass =
  cMyClass with no properties.
>> oMyClass.SomeMethod
ans =
Hello world
```

Unfortunately, I failed to invoke `SomeMethod` as a normal function from with folder `@cMyClass`:

```
>> cd @cMyClass
>> clear all; clear classes
>> rehash
>> o=struct
o =
struct with no fields.
>> SomeMethod(o)
Undefined function or variable 'SomeMethod'.
```

However, I succeeded in invoking `SomeMethod` from outside of `@cMyClass`.  I used a shell to copy SomeMethod.m up one level to `@cMyClass/..` (in POSIX path notation), then executed:

```
>> cd .. % Go to @cMyClass/..
>> clear all; clear classes
>> rehash
>> o=struct
o =
struct with no fields.
>> SomeMethod(o)
ans =
Hello world
```

Another illustration of success when the function doesn't reside in a folders starting with `@` is to copy `@cMyClass` to `not_cMyClass` and execute:

```
>> cd not_cMyClass
> clear all; clear classes
>> rehash
>> o=struct
o = 
struct with no fields.
>> SomeMethod(o)
ans =
Hello world
```

The puzzling thing is that when Matlab's current working directory is `@cMyClass`, `cMyClass` is not recognized as a class and so SomeMethod.m should not be interpretted as a method file:

```
>> cd ..\@cMyClass\
>> clear all
>> clear classes
>> rehash
>> c=cMyClass
Undefined function or variable 'cMyClass'.
```

In other words, one would expect `SomeMethod.m` to be interpretted as a normal function file, in the same way as it is when it resides in `not_cMyClass` and `@cMyClass/..` above.

In lieu of a solution, I have to maintain a copy of `SomeMethod.m` outside of folder `@cMyClass`, and keep manually keep the two copies synchronized.  Human error becomes a hazard.

Please note that since I am using Cygwin on a Microsoft Windows machine, both `/` and `\` get used as a path separator, depending on the context.

Note that creating a virtual copy by using unix's `ln -s` or by creating a Microsoft Windows shortcut in `@cMyClass/..` does not work.  Matlab will not recognize these as m-files.

Comment: Can we see a code snippet please? Your description is clear, but that would make everything easier.

Comment: You could use symbolic links to these functions in a separate folder. (On a Mac at least) it will not work to just create a symbolic link to the folder containing the functions, as a `cd` to the symbolic link will be resolved by MATLAB to the original path.

Comment: I added further comment near the end to describe my unsuccessful experimentation with soft links.  I'm also finding that the consequence of this inability to invoke methods as non-method function is greater than I feared, and describe this near the end as well.

Comment: Oops.  That last sentence is not valid, but I can no longer remove it.  The 5 minute window has passed.

Comment: @user36800: It sounds like you have a function `SomeMethod` that you want to be able to call for any object (without having to preface it with a class name), but it should also do some things slightly differently when handling an object of `cMyClass` (hence why you want it to be a method)? And you want to only maintain one copy of the function?

Comment: Not quite.  It is properly situated as a class method.  The thing is, I'm in a wholesale transition of the code, and it doesn't (I can't expect it to run).  I am only trying to sort out the front end of the method without all the infrastructure from the class object itself.  The front end of the code doesn't require access to any other object properties.  So I pass it a fake object instead.

Comment: The approach seems to work, since I can iteratively modify and test the code for the method by copying it out of the folder for that class definition.  But I would rather evolve the code in place so that I don't have yet another file in another location to track.  There are many, many method m-files in the project.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. MATLAB dispatches function calls based on the types of the arguments. A function `cMyClass/func` will be called for `func(obj)` if `obj` is of type `cMyClass`. If not, a different `func` will be called. You will get an error if `func` is not defined for whatever class `obj` is, and there is no `func` outside of a class directory.

There is no way to call `@cMyClass/func.m` using `func({})` or some such syntax. If you want to be able to call this function with an empty object, you need to modify your class so that `cMyClass` (the class constructor) returns an empty object. Then you can do `func(cMyClass)`.

The other alternative is to make `func` a [static method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html). Then you can call it wuth `cMyClass.func`.

Do note that for troubleshooting and debugging, you can still set breakpoints and debug as you would any other function. I really don't see the need to call such a function with an illegal input...

Comment: I've added example code to illustrate why one would expect `SomeMethod.m` to be interpretted as a normal (non-method) function, as well as to show the invocation of `SomeMethod` with a valid argument when it is being invoked as a non-method function.

Comment: BTW, I'm interested in invoking the function outside of the context of a method because I'm doing wholesale recoding, so not all code across the class is self-consistent during the change-over.  However, I still want to code-a-little, test-a-little.

Comment: @user36800: This part is surprising: "when Matlab's current working directory is `@cMyClass`, `cMyClass` is not recognized as a class". I had not noticed this before. The problem with running a class method as a stand-alone function is that code inside class methods is interpreted differently. For example indexing works differently, the overloaded indexing operator is not called.

Comment: It would still be useful to be able to invoke the m-file as a non-method function using `keyboard` to prevent execution from reaching code that would be problematic outside the context of a method invocation.  Otherwise, I end up copying the m-file elsewhere, and to ensure that I modify the right one and keep the two synced.  Human error becomes a problem.